# Can you import a save from The Walking Dead Season 2 to Michonne?

Tags: the-walking-dead-michonne

If I can import a save, how do I do it?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote.  Season 2 had a save import feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michonne is a separate mini series. As far as I know they are not connected, and one is not the continuation of the other (unlike S3 will be, for S2) so you wouldn't get much use of importing it...

Answer (score 1):

> Can you import a save from The Walking Dead Season 2 to Michonne?

No.

Choices made in Season 1 or 2 are not incorporated into the Michonne game.

From the [Telltale Forums](https://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/96029/the-walking-dead-unofficial-faq-please-read-before-posting-updated-1-30-with-more-michonne-info):

> **(12) Will a DLC episode be released for Season Two, like with 400 Days in Season One?**
>
> No. However, a three episode miniseries called The Walking Dead: Michonne will be released. This miniseries was originally announced as DLC for The Walking Dead: Season Two, however in late 2015, it was announced that it would be a standalone miniseries that would not require any other game to play.